# use progressbarjs to count numbers , not percentage

Tags: javascript, module, progress-bar

I try to use this tool, [progressbarjs](http://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/). More info [here](http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I just want to count from 0 to 40000 , with step 10000.

My code right now is

```
var jake= new ProgressBar.Circle('#jake', {
                        color: '#000',
                        duration: 1500,
                        strokeWidth: 8,
                        trailWidth: 7,
                        easing: 'easeIn'

 });

 for (i = 0; i<= 40000; i = i+1000){
      jake.animate(i,  function() {
           circleT.setText(i);
      });

  }
```

In animation, the circle completes many times with a non-smooth motion and the text stops in 41000, not 40000.

How do I fix this? I dont have a clue, I need help, I dont quite get how this library works.

Thanks

Comment: Why not multiply the percent by 400. That should work just fine :) This won't step up in 1000's but it will go from 0 - 40000 rather than 0-100

Comment: @NewToJS Can you give me an example and help me, I am really confused now. Thanks

Comment: What is `circleT` in your code? Can you provide the code in a JSFiddle?

Comment: If your current progress bar is displaying 0-100, you can calculate what 1% of 40000 is, by doing that if you 40000*1/100 = 400 so when the progress updates, progress*400 will = from 0 to 40000 in progress. Example: Progress is at 40%,  if you 40*400=16,000. 16,000 =  40% of 40000. So whatever the % of progress, multiply that by 400. The result will be the new progress from 0-100 to 0-40000.

Comment: @slevin I have created a little demo to show you what I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/n6j4cw2j/ If your current progressbar returns `0-100` this shouldn't be too hard to  work in as all you need from this is the `*400`  adding to your existing progress output. I haven't posted this as a answer as I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for and I haven't looked into the `progressbarjs`  you're using as I have to leave for work any time soon.